# RPM upgrade skips file

Tags: linux, rpm, rpm-spec

I have a rpm which installs `.war` file to `/opt/myLocation/`. This file is used by tomcat - it simply unzips it and moves the unzipped files to different location.

I want to make a rpm upgrade with rpm -U myPackage.rpm but it does not overwrite the file inside /opt/myLocation'

I used -vv to have a view what's going on and here is the problem:

```
D: fini      100644  1 ( 496, 492)  13245703 /opt/myLocation/myFile.war skip
```

I tried `rpm -U --force` `-F` but no luck.

Any idea what might be happening here?

Comment: The likely pitfall is that your package did not upgrade: it used the same version+release.  There's not enough information in the question to be certain.

Comment: Can you show rpm -U output ?

Comment: maybe the rpm installs the new file under /opt/myLocation/myFile.war.rpmnew ?

Comment: @ChrisMaes: unfortunately not. When I use --replacefiles it seems to be working. Although I am not sure that this is the right solution.

Comment: what does `rpm -qf /opt/myLocation/myFile.war` give you? It gives you the owner of this file. Maybe the problem lies there...